# Cmdlet pass a list of parameters at once through a Pipeline, not individual list items

Tags: c#, powershell, pipeline, powershell-cmdlet

I am creating a Powershell    `System.Management.AutomationCmdlet.Cmdlet`   for passing a list of strings through a Pipeline to a Cmdlet this way:

```
  [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Add, "Signature")]
  public class AddSignature : Cmdlet
...
    [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = true)]
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
...
```

Now, in the overloaded "ProcessRecord" method I get only one item at a time `Items.Count == 1` 3 times(instead of getting the full List at once passed through the pipeline).

```
'item1','item2','item3' | Add-Signature
```

Is there a possibility to pass the whole list of items(returned by Get-ChildItem) at once? I only get one item at a time.

Basically I want to have the same behaviour using the pipeline as if I am using the command like this (`Items.Count == 3`)

```
Add-Signature -Items "item1","item2","item3"
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I have been wondering the same thing actually, although my focus was to use this directly from Powershell, not in C#. I thought there would be some attribute or official way of doing this.

The terms I've seen used are *stall* as in "stalling the pipeline" or sometimes *buffer*. There are 2 official cmdlets I can think of which do this: `Sort-Object` stalls because it needs all of the objects before it can sort them. `Format-Table -Autosize` stalls because it needs all of the objects before it can figure out how to size the columns.

I have come up with this workaround in Powershell:

```
function Stall-Pipeline {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(
        ValueFromPipeline
    )]
    [String]
    $Msg
)

    Begin {
        Write-Verbose "Begin"
        $all = @()
    }

    Process {
        Write-Verbose "Process"
        $all += $Msg
    }

    End {
        Write-Verbose "End"
        foreach($item in $all) {
            # processing 
            $item # processed item
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially I am using the `begin` block to initialize a variable that will hold all the results. The `process` block adds to that variable, then the `end` block does all of the actual processing and sends the items out to the pipeline.

You can call this with `-Verbose` to see when each block is being called.

If there is a better way, a more official or supported way, I am very interested in knowing what that is.

Comment: I also tought at doing the actual  work in the "End" method, althought this does not really fit into the meaning of this method. Probably this will be the way to go if I am not finding a better solution.